# Do I need to release the object in php?

Tags: php, object, memory-management, programming-languages

Previously I've used Objective-C in iPhone Development.  It seems I need to do some work in the back-end site, I chose PHP for this.  In Objective-C, I need to release objects after I use them.  Do I need to do this in PHP also? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

99.9% of the time, no you do not need to delete the object. PHP has a garbage collector that will handle that for you. The garbage collector will free a given instance of memory once it is no longer needed in your code.

To read more:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php

Answer (score 0):

Not for memory, PHP uses garbage collection. Objects are released at some point after they become unreachable (**not** instantly as some simplified introductions claim) to your code. This includes reference cycles since a few versions (a references b, b references a) - previously, it used reference counting only and thus failed in the face of such cycles.

Resources (files, database connections, etc.) might happen to be closed when they are collected, but since the time of collection is non-deterministic and whether that closes them depends on the resource in question, it's propably a very bad idea to just leave them when you're done with them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't except for persistent database connections.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't! Php has a [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) that take care of memory handling for you.

Comment: I highly doubt `unset` will force destruction. Even if it triggered a GC cycle (again, very impropably), no GC'd language I'm aware of allows (except D, where GC is explicitly optional) deleting an object when it's still referenced as that would destroy 50% of what makes GC useful (no dangling pointers).

Comment: probably unset () does not free the memory immediately as it would  send a [myObj release] message. But it's the closest thing to release message that I know in PHP

Comment: The thing is that there is no such thing in any purely-GC'd language. Not even something close. Telling people this is close to it is propably harmful (they'll propably spam it and make their code unreadable), telling them it's exactly that (as you do) it plain wrong.

Comment: You're right! Make such a statement may confuse a unfamiliar user and can spread bad practice. I will edit my answer to avoid future misunderstandings